# Is traveling to Ireland from CDG or AMS airports through domestic terminals?

Tags: transit, ireland, ams, cdg

Is traveling from AMS or CDG airports to any Irish airport considered as a domestic flight or and international flight?

In other words, do I have to pass through the security check in the transit or I will only change terminals or gates?

Comment: Which Irish airport would you be landing at? Depending on how it's organized, domestic vs. international might not be the most relevant distinction.

Comment: I don't think the specific Irish airport is relevant. The distinction domestic vs. international depend on the countries not on the airports. The only difference could be the arrival terminal at the Irish airport.

Comment: @Lorenzo Well, that's exactly why the distinction is superficial and irrelevant. The OP wants to know whether there will be a safety check in transit and that depends on the airport, airline, destination, etc. Same thing for customs, passport checks, check-in time or luggage check-through at various European airports. Even the terminals need not be split along those lines. It's only in the US that there is such a sharp distinction between “domestic” and “international”.

Comment: This whole domestic vs. international business is confusing the issue, we already have three answers expressing different views on what is a domestic flight while still completely failing to address your question on security checks or provide any actual information on Irish airports. I would suggest editing out the “domestic flight” question and focusing on the practical aspects highlighted at the end.

Comment: @Relaxed: No, it's not. Many European airports have Schengen/Non-Schengen departures and arrivals, which is a similar distinction.

Comment: @MSalters Well, no, that's precisely my point, for some purpose it's Schengen vs. non-Schengen and not international vs. domestic. But for other purposes (like check-in time), it will be long-haul vs. short-haul, etc. and even the necessary separation between Schengen and non-Schengen passengers can be maintained within one terminal or with a single security check-point for the whole airport. Depending on the question (luggage, passport, security, etc.), the specific destination or airline will matter and the notion that flights are either domestic or international only confuses the matter.

Comment: @Relaxed: The question was about terminals. No Schengen airport that I'm aware of has three types: Domestic, International-Schengen and International-Other. The first two are always merged. Thus "domestic" is a sensible label here, it refers to terminals which serve domestic flights and possibly some other flights. And the question is whether in Ireland, _some other flights_ includes flights from NL and FR.

Comment: @MSalters Given the level of confusion in the answers to these and other questions, I still don't think it is.

Comment: @MSalters Many airports, including Amsterdam, have physical terminals organized by airline with flights to and from Schengen destinations flying from widely different parts of the airports but flights from the same airline flying from different part of the same terminal (typically with a different letter code but that's a detail). Here again Schengen = domestic = this or that terminal would be a completely wrong implication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since AMS (Amsterdam Schiphol) is in the Netherlands and CDG (Paris Charles De Gaulle) is in France, both in the Schengen area, any flight to Ireland, which is not in the Schengen area, will definitely be considered as an international flight.

Domestic flights are usually defined as flights within the same country, but flights between two Schengen countries can be considered domestic as well. However, this is not the case for Ireland.

Regarding the security check, I believe it depends on the specific airport and from where you are connecting. At CDG I was once allowed to board a flight to the USA connecting from an international flight from Europe at a different terminal without passing through the security check again. At other airports, in a similar situation, I was required to go through security checks.

Comment: "Domestic flights are only within the same country." This is not true, a flight between two Schengen countries is considered domestic.

Comment: Yes, I used the term "domestic" in the meaning of "same country". I would refer to a flight between two Schengen counties as a "Schengen flight", but it is true that such a flight is considered as if it was a domestic flight. I'm modifying my answer as it could be confusing in this sense.

Comment: @fkraiem It's not particularly helpful to insist on the distinction, there are different rules for flights from different destinations, with different overlapping categories (e.g. Schengen area is relevant for passport checks, EU for customs, long-haul vs. short-haul for check-in times, some countries have slightly different rules for flights to their oversee territories, etc.) Whether a Schengen-bound flight fits the OP's definition of “domestic flight” is anyone's guess.

Comment: The question is not about either CDG or AMS but about Irish airports, do you have any experience with those?

Comment: @Relaxed: Schengen is restricted to EU/EFTA countries, so Schengen implies no customs. Also, Ireland has no overseas territories.

Comment: @MSalters Not true, the EFTA does not imply a complete lack of customs (technically neither does EU or EEA membership but limits between Switzerland and the rest of the EEA are much more stringent than internal limits) and obviously Ireland isn't in the Schengen area but still part of the EU. Not that my arguments really depend on that's all the more reason to phrase practical questions precisely instead of fooling oneself in thinking that knowing whether a flight is “domestic” will tell you anything you need to know about it.

Answer (score 2):

That would be international - AMS and CDG are in the Schengen zone, Ireland isn't.

Comment: What about safety checks in transit?

Comment: Done on all flights nowadays, before departure.

Answer (score 1):

It would definitely be arriving into Ireland as an "international" arrival. Same as departing from Ireland to either to AMS or CDG. As such you would need a valid passport for this flight.

The only flights to and from Ireland that are classed as domestic are from within Ireland or the UK and you can travel on a EU issued driving licence or national identity card.

Comment: You can certainly travel to Ireland from either Paris or Amsterdam with a national ID card. I lived and worked there as a foreigner without even holding a passport.

Comment: Depending on your original country of residence, ie someone with a Nigerian I.D card couldn't do this.

Comment: Europe (Schengen area*)
When crossing the Schengen area's borders, any citizen of a country located outside the schengen area must possess a passport that is valid for at least 3 months after the intended departure date from the Schengen area. The passport must have been issued within the last 10 years.
The Schengen area includes 26 countries: Austria, Belgium, Czech Republic, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Norway, Netherlands, Poland, Portugal, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden and Switzerland.